# Why can't I find a table in a database?

Tags: sql-server

I have this code:

```
USE mydb;

  create table #payments 
  (   id int,    contract_ID varchar(20),    payment_number int,    payment_status varchar(20));

  insert   #payments (id, contract_id, payment_number, payment_status)
  values
  (1, 'contract1', 1, 'Processed'),
  (2, 'contract1', 2, 'Received'),
  (3, 'contract2', 1, 'Processed'),
  (4, 'contract2', 2, 'Approved'),
  (5, 'contract1', 3, 'Approved'),
  (6, 'contract2', 3, 'Processed');
```

Is it correct that the above SQL script creates a table named `#payments` in the database 'mydb'?

When I run the above for the second time, SSMS says

> There is already an object named '#payments' in the database.

But why can't I find the table in the output of this query?

```
USE mydb;

SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  GROUP BY TABLE_NAME
```

Answer (score 4):

> Is it correct that the above SQL script creates a table named #payments in the database 'mydb'?

No, that's not correct.

`#` indicates a *temporary* table, it's created in `tempdb`

```
select Object_Id('tempdb.dbo.#payments');

select *
from tempdb.sys.tables
where name like '#payments%';
```

You'll see it exists with a negative object ID and name appended with a long "uniquifier".

Likewise prefixing any object name with `#` indicates it is a temporary object and will be managed for you in tempdb. Objects created with a single hash prefix are scoped to your own session, a double hash indicates they are global and visible to all sessions. Temporary objects are automatically dropped when they go out of scope, ie, are no longer referenced.

Answer (score -2):

IN MSSQL when we create temp table we use #

use mydb;

create table #payments
(   id int,    contract_ID varchar(20),    payment_number int,    payment_status varchar(20));

insert into  #payments (id, contract_id, payment_number, payment_status)
values
(1, 'contract1', 1, 'Processed'),
(2, 'contract1', 2, 'Received'),
(3, 'contract2', 1, 'Processed'),
(4, 'contract2', 2, 'Approved'),
(5, 'contract1', 3, 'Approved'),
(6, 'contract2', 3, 'Processed');

select * from #payments

You can find table by using below query:
select * from tempdb..sysobjects

Comment: You need to explain why.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM mydb.payments;`? I would hope the OP doesn't have a schema called `mydb` on their database `mydb`. That would be confusing. *"Don't give hashtag (#) while writing table name."* Why not? Temporary tables have their uses.